# Adicionar Extensões do PHP no Docker Compose

Tags: php, docker

qual seria a melhor forma de adicionar as extensões do PHP como a biblioteca GD dentre outras diretamente no docker-compose.yml?

Meu arquivo está conforme abaixo:

```
nginx:
    image: tutum/nginx
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    links:
        - phpfpm
    volumes:
        - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
        - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

        - ./logs/nginx-error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
        - ./logs/nginx-access.log:/var/log/nginx/access.log
phpfpm:
    image: php:fpm
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
        - ./public:/usr/share/nginx/html
        - ./custom.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
mysql:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: lista
    MYSQL_USER: root
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
  command: mysqld --innodb-buffer-pool-size=1024M
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
```

Comment: Se for de alguma ajuda, você pode usar uma imagem oficial que já venha com as extensões mais comuns do `php`,dá uma olhada [nisso](https://github.com/Chialab/docker-php). Ou pode usar esses *Dockerfiles* como base pra montar o seu.

Comment: Você pode me informar como eu faria para informar essa imagem em meu docker-compose?

Comment: Você constrói sua própria imagem do php (usando por base essas que te indiquei) e depois só referencia no `image`, ao invés de chamar essa que tá usando. Ex: [Dockerfile](https://github.com/Chialab/docker-php/blob/master/7.0/fpm/Dockerfile) para `php 7.0-fpm`. Sabe como construir images com o *Dockerfile*?

Comment: não sei, estou começando a trabalhar com Docker agora, vou dar uma pesquisada sobre.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse [artigo](https://churrops.io/2017/09/08/docker-construindo-suas-imagens-com-dockerfile/), e recomendo o [play-with-docker](https://labs.play-with-docker.com/) pra treinar na prática ;)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o comando `command` para instalar uma nova extensão:

```
# docker-compose.yml
phpfpm:
    command: sh -c "apk update && apk upgrade && apk add postgresql-dev && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql && php-fpm"
    container_name: phpfpm
    image: php:7.2-fpm-alpine

# $ docker exec -it phpfpm php -m | grep pdo
```

Porém, tenho certeza que não é isso que você quer já que `command` é executado toda vez que seus serviços sobem com `docker-compose up`.

Como é dito no própio [repositório oficial](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) do PHP no Docker Hub, o recomendado é construir uma nova imagem com as suas extensões via `Dockerfile`.

```
# phpfpm.Dockerfile
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add postgresql-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql
```

E deixar o Docker Compose criar e gerenciar seus containers:

```
# docker-compose.yml
phpfpm:
    build: ./phpfpm.Dockerfile
    container_name: phpfpm

# $ docker exec -it phpfpm php -m | grep pdo
```